# Transition rates and probabilities of a continuous markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

A certain type of component has two states: 0 = OFF and 1 = OPERATING. In state 0 , the process remains there an exponential amount of time with rate $ \alpha$, and then moves to state 1. The component spends an exponential amount of time with rate $\beta$ in state 1 after which the process returns to state 0. A system consists of two such components A and B. Assume that the amounts of time the components spend in the states are independent of one another and have rates given by the following.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Off Rate($\alpha$)} & \text{Operating Rate($\beta$)} \\ \hline
\text{A} & 2 & 4 \\ \hline
\text{B} & 3 & 6 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Consider the continuous Markov chain with states ${0,A,B,2}$ representing the component currently operating. Enumerate the transition rates $v_i$ and the transitional probabilities $p_ij$.

My transition rates are $v_0 = 2, v_A =1, v_B =3, v_2 = 3 $. Is my answer right?How do I get the transitional probabilities? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you find these $\nu_i$?

Comment: I used this definition/reference. "A continuous-time markov chain is a stochastic process having the properties that each time it enters state i the amount of time it spends in that state before making a transition into a different state is exponential with rate $v_i$." So I thought that $v_0$ is 2 since it is the time/rate at which the two components are off.